# How to display top 3 data label in piechart highchart

Tags: angularjs, web, highcharts

I have a requirement where I want my pie chart to display only top 3 data label instead of displaying all and filling the space. Is there any inbuilt highchart api available or a best solution to achieve this?

Here is my jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/k80ayx1t/

```
            plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        }
```

I have searched enough and tried to find the solution before posting this question but didn't find any help.

Comment: You can use dataLabels.formatter function: http://jsfiddle.net/k80ayx1t/1/

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzBlachliński it seems to be working but in your fiddle it shows, value in data label, but I want Name in data label. I am little new to highchart, can you please help me to display Top 3 name in data label instead of value.

Comment: Got it.. I returned " this.key " instead of val, and it worked. If possible please add this comment as answer and I will mark it as Answered. it may help other users. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5njsu0vo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dataLabels.formatter function for returning only specific dataLabels (for points thats value is big enough).

```
formatter: function() {
          var val = this.y,
            allData = $.extend(true, [], this.series.processedYData).sort(),
            length = allData.length;
          if (length - 4 >= 0 && val > allData[length - 4])
            return val;
}
```

I am sorting my yValues and then I am checking if my dataLabels points y value is bigger or equal to the third y value of my series. If it is bigger or equal, I am returning value, else I am not returning anything.

Here you can find an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/k80ayx1t/1/